# regex-replace-text-outside-html <a> tags

Tags: java, html, regex, replace

I have this HTML:

```
"This is simple html <a href='google.com'>text</a><span class='simple'>simple simple text text</span> text"
```

I need to match only words that are outside  HTML tag. I mean if I want to match “simple” and “text” I should get the results only from inside of HTML tags except for  tag.

I was close with this regexp `(text|simple)(?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/)` but I am excluding all the html tags.

Comment: It is usually possible to do with regex, but [greatly discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3832970). Please explain why you need to do it with regex. Add the details about the programming language.

Comment: A programming language is Java. I am replacing content in the HTML request I've received from the server and I need to replace some word occurrences but I need to ignore already existing links.

Comment: ... Might I refer you to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved that already

```
(?!([^<]+)?>)(?!<a[^>]*?>)(\text\b)(?![^<]*?</a>)
```